# From the time Ubuntu font is released, how long will it take for major websites(facebook, yahoo, google etc.) to support it?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

The title explains it already...

Comment: Sorry, the title doesn't really explain anything. What font are you talking about? And what do you mean by "support"? What do you envisage these websites doing with it?

Comment: Ubuntu font. :-)

Comment: What do you mean with support it? Do you know that you can use customized stylesheets for most major browsers that can override which font is used on a webpage?

Comment: The title explains nothing, and you don't even try clarifying it based on the comments...

Comment: Fonts aren't dictated by websites so much as they are by the browsers themselves. Closing because this question appears to be too vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font is supported on any website that uses generic font families - serif, sans and mono. If you want the Ubuntu font to be used, you will need to set the default sans font (the Ubuntu font will be a sans font I think) in your browser options to the Ubuntu font. You could even set the serif font to the Ubuntu font but you will get a 'sans' look instead of a 'serif' look.

[image: fonts]

It is unlikely that a website will set the font specifically to the Ubuntu font, if that's what you mean. Using a specific font is discouraged in web design because users might not have this font on their system. The closest you will get (this is only likely to happen on Ubuntu related sites) is to have sites that say 'use the Ubuntu font if possible and fall back to the default sans font if the Ubuntu font is not installed' by setting the font-family to "ubuntu,sans-serif".

Comment: That's what I meant. Sorry for not making it clear. I kinda thought that most websites, if not all, are compelled to support a font that is used by a major operating system. Apparently my understanding was wrong. Thanks for all the response :-)

Answer (score 1):

Supported? never.

But if you like to use it anyway, take a look at http://code.google.com/webfonts or http://typekit.com/

However, this question belongs more to http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since most websites only use the most standard fonts, the answer is: Probably never.

But seriously... :)

Comment: *Somebody* must be using the Ubuntu Font Family 100+ million times per month on their websites!  :-)  See: http://www.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Ubuntu&subset=latin#description